# Find the difference between min and max element, while we can perform a operation on element in array?

Tags: algorithm

Q: We are given an array `A` and an element `K`. We can multiply and divide(if `K` is factor of element) any element of array, `any number of time`. And our objective is to find `minimum difference` between maximum and minimum element of the array.

For exp 1. `A = [3,4,5,6,7] K = 2`, then ans is `3`.

Explanation: Multiply `3` by `2`, then `[4,5,6,6,7]` ==> `(7-4)` is optimal

---

exp2: `A = [48,56,32,64]`, `K = 2`, its ans = `2`

explanation2: divide each element by `K`, we get `A = [24,28,16,32]`, here ans = `16`, we repeat this step 2 times, we get `A = [12,14,8,16]` ==> `[6,7,4,8]`, here ans = `4`, which is still not the optimal. We can multiply `4` by `K`, and we get `A = [6,7,8,8]`, our ans will be `2`.

---

Note: It is also possible to get optimal solution, without performing any operation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: While all elements of `A` are divisible by `K` divide them all by `K`. Eventually at least one of its elements is not divisible by `K`. Let `a` and `b` be the smallest and largest elements of (the new) `A` that are not divisible by `K`. They could be equal. For each element `x` of (the new) `A` that is outside of the interval `[a,b]` find its factor `pow(K, n)*x` that is closest to the interval `[a,b]`. You do this by multiplying by `K`, if `x< a`, or dividing by `K`, if `x>b`, until the distance to `[a,b]` stops decreasing.

Comment: Return the difference between the maximum and minimum of the resulting `A`.

Comment: Acc to your statement, `Let a and b be the smallest and largest elements of (the new) A that are not divisible by K`, from `[3,4,5,6,7] ` we get `[3,7]` Now, every other element is lie in the interval, then we can't do multiplication of `3` with `K` which gives us optimal solution. please correct me, what i am missing?

Comment: You are right. My algorithm is not correct, because `a` could still be multiplied to make the interval [a'=5, b=7] smaller. But possibly to correct it it might be enough to insert this step. This is, allow the `x` above to be also `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Question explanation is not clear so what i assumed is:
 we can only divide if it is divisible by k and only multiply if it is not divisible by k.

```
N is array size , k is given number and A[i] are elements in array
```

Now make vector for each element's possible values and there won't be much entries in the vector

case 1: when A[i] not divisible by k then `v[i] = {A[i], A[i]*k}<br>`

case 2: when A[i] is divisible by k then `v[i] = {A[i], A[i]/k,...}`

Sort the vectors

now make a `set<pair<int , pair<int , int>>>`
then insert first element of each vector in set like

```
{ value of first element in vector, {0(index of value in that vector), index of that vector}}
```

now make one variable `ans = max value in set - min value in set`

now keep removing minimum element in set and push next element of that vector in set if it exist or break the loop and also keep updating the answer.

NOTE:

`{ value of first element in vector,{0(index of value in that vector),index of that vector}}`

`(index of value in that vector)` is used for pushing next element of that vector in the set